# Почему Pytelegrambotapi не устанавливается

Tags: python

Пишу `pip install pytelegrambotapi`  и выходит это?

```
Requirement already satisfied: pytelegrambotapi in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pytelegrambotapi) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pytelegrambotapi) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pytelegrambotapi) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pytelegrambotapi) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->pytelegrambotapi) (2022.12.7)
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!

В выводе указано, что библиотека `pytelegrambotapi` уже установлена. Если при запуске кода, вы получаете ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError`, это может быть связано со следующими обстоятельствами:

1. Вы могли опечататься в коде. Проверьте, что вы подключаете библиотеку с помощью строчки `import telebot`
2. Вы можете запускать код с помощью виртуального окружения (`vitrualenv`, `venv`). Если это так, то вам нужно установить пакет именно в виртуальное окружение, а не в систему

Если ни один из этих вариантов не сработал, напишите в комментариях под моим ответом. Если останутся вопросы, буду рад на них ответить